# Cannot take screenshots of Android L emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-sdk

No matter which method I use, I cannot take screenshots of the Android L emulator. I tried through Android Studio, using the Android Device Monitor app, and through adb with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892305/how-to-take-screenshot-in-android-emulator) method (first answer) which produces a 0 byte file. I can take screenshots fine with all my other emulators. However, this emulator is a bit different than my others. For the first time, I am using the X86 system image and I enabled "Use host GPU". Is there some new way of taking screenshots I don't know about?

Comment: Do you need to take screenshots inside the emulator or can you use the OSs screenshot function?

Comment: Are you using windows? Why not `ALT + Print Screen` it the easy way? Or in Linux you could use `gnome-screenshot` or `gnome-screenshot -w` or in the UI itself with the emulator as the the  current active window alone, select “Grab the Current Window” and click “Take Screenshot”.

Answer (score 3):

[image: See the Image]
Screen Shot of Emulator:
Firstly start the emulator then go to the DDMS
please select the emulator then left side we have button Screen Capture click this button screen Shot is taken.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your application
2. Click `Android` Icon >> `Screen Capture` Icon from android studio
3. `Save`

Tutorial: [How to take screenshot from android studio](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/take-screenshot-of-android-app-from-android-studio.html)